# SQL Server 2008 Grant Select Permission

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-permissions

I am having trouble adding a user to a test database I set up on my local machine.  I have added the user fine but the user does not have permission to `SELECT` (Or anything else for that matter) on the database.  I have tried gone the the permission tab under the server, the database, and the table (there is only one it is a very simple database just for testing) and selected grant for every single option yet it still does not work.  I have also tried doing a Transact-SQL command like:

```
use testing

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT TO User
```

and a couple of other combinations that return successfully but I still do not have permission to select data from the table.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you verified that the user can log in?  And that you're granting with a user other than the user that is having the select issue?

Answer (score 3):

Add the user to the db_datareader role to give the user select access to all of the tables.

Answer (score 2):

Add the user to the public database role and they should be able to SELECT against the database (unless you have changed the public role's permissions).